# backbone.js router - simple example doesn't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Having -

**default.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="json2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone.js"></script>
        <script>
            Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routers: {
                    "*action" : "func"
                },
                func: function (action) {
                    console.log(action);

                }
            });

            new Router();
            Backbone.history.start(); 
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

According to the `routers` format it has to print to the `console` the suffix after the `#` .

For example for the path `default.html#hello` it has to print `hello` on the `console` , but in actually nothing printed .

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routes need to be defined in the `routes` key, not `routers`:

```
        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                "*action" : "func"
            },
            func: function (action) {
                console.log(action);

            }
        });
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/WJ5V7/](http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/WJ5V7/)